# Find out which app launched my cocoa app

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have been searching all around for a way to check which app did launch my cocoa app.

It seems I cannot use NSWorkspaceDidDectivateApplicationNotification because it starts tracking after the app was launched. Do someone know how to do this? The app in question is a status bar app, not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: Unless the launching app takes specific steps to pass such information along in some custom manner (arguments, extra parameters on the initial Apple Event, etc.), I don't believe there's a way. Why do you want to know? If you explain your ultimate goal — what you would do with this information — maybe somebody can suggest a different way to get there.

Comment: I see. What I want to do is activate the launcher app immediately after startup. This is because I want my app to behave the same way all the time. When launched the app stays in focus which do cause some glitches. As soon as the app is deactivated (either by clicking anywhere outside of it or programmatically by activating random app) everything behaves consistently.

For some reason NSRunningApplication.currentApplication().hide() won't work. Probably because the app is a status bar app.

Comment: It seems that if one app launches another with Launch Services or NSWorkspace, the second app's parent process is launchd.  Disappointing.